# What are the odds of getting a trade token in clan war?

Tags: clash-royale

After each participation in clan war with the war battle played, you get some rewards.

What are the odds of getting any trade token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a recent update, your average chance is 25%. Basically, there now exists a cycle of 8 War loots, of which 2 have Trade Tokens, 1 has Gems and 5 have Gold.
If I'm not wrong, the chances for each rarity remain the same (e.g. *if* you get a token, there's a 40% chance to be Legendary, 30% chance to be Epic, 20% to be Rare and 10% to be Common).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://clashfordummies.com/2018/09/07/trade-tokens-drop-rates-odds-war-bounties-in-clash-royale/) and this [datamine reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/9dgbg5/clash_royale_241_datamined/), there is a 10% chance to receive a token. The rates are broken down as follows:

- Legendary token: 4%
- Epic token: 3%
- Rare token: 2%
- Common token: 1%

**Note:** This could change at any time.

Comment: I think these odds were modified recently - I got 3 epic tokens in 3 consecutive wars, which, if I did my math correctly, is about 1 in 37 thousand. I know I'm not that lucky... I also average about 1 trade token in 3 wars.